# How can I get this Cover Page/ Title Page to work in my LaTeX file?

Tags: titles, double-sided, bookcover

I am making my very first LaTeX typeset thesis. I am planning on printing two versions of this thesis (Onesided for corrections and two-sided for final submission).

I want to incorporate this exact format for Cover Page and Title Page which I found on Page 6 of the document '[Writing a Thesis with LaTeX' by Lapo F. Mori](https://tug.org/pracjourn/2008-1/mori/mori.pdf)'.

I've given this a go -

``

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,titlepage,oneside]{book}
 \usepackage[DIV=14,BCOR=2mm,headinclude=true,footinclude=false]{typearea}
 \usepackage{setspace}
 \setstretch{1.1}
 \KOMAoptions{DIV=last}

\makeatletter
\if@twoside
   \newlength{\myoffset}
   \setlength{\myoffset}{12mm}
   \addtolength{\hoffset}{\myoffset}
   \addtolength{\evensidemargin}{-2.0\myoffset}
\fi
\makeatother


\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{charter} 
\usepackage{eso-pic}        
\usepackage{graphicx}
%\graphicspath{{images/}}   
\usepackage{xcolor} 

\definecolor{tcdblue}{RGB}{14,115,185} 
\definecolor{tcdgrey}{RGB}{83,86,90}

\begin{document}

\AddToShipoutPictureBG*{\includegraphics[width=\paperwidth]{logo1}}

\centering
\textbf{Firstname Surname}
\vspace{5cm}
\textbf{\LARGE{NAME of THESIS IN ALL CAPITAL LETTERS}}
\vspace{0.5cm}
\textbf{A Thesis in Doctor of Philosophy}
\vspace{11cm}
\textbf{Name of University}
\vspace{1cm}
Month 2019
\begin{titlepage}
\begin{center}
% \vspace*{1cm}
\includegraphics[width=0.2\textwidth]{logo1} \\

\textcolor{tcdgrey}{\textrm{\textbf{\textsc{Name of University}}}} \\
\textcolor{tcdgrey}{Name of University in Local Language} \\         
\textcolor{tcdblue}{Department/Faculty Name} \\

\hrulefill\par

\textrm{A dissertation submitted in partial fulfillment of the requirements for the degree of Doctor of Philosophy in Biochemistry \& Immunology}

\vspace{1.5cm}
NAME of THESIS IN ALL CAPITAL LETTERS 
\vspace{1.5cm}

Thesis/Dissertation by \\
\vspace{0.2cm} 
\textbf{Author Name}
\vspace{1.5cm}

\begin{flushleft}     
Examiners \\
\vspace{0.2cm}
Prof 1 Firstname SURNAME \dotfill \\
Prof 2 Firstname SURNAME \dotfill \\
\vspace{0.5cm}
Candidate \\
\vspace{0.2cm}
Firstname SURNAME     
\end{flushleft}
\vfill
\hrulefill\par
Academic Year 2019/2012 \\
Country \\
Date
\end{center}
\end{titlepage}
\end{document}
```

``

And this is the output that I get -

[image: Cover Page]

[image: Title Page]

How can I make my output exactly similar to the one in the linked PDF (while implementing my own fonts which is CharterBT and not CMR)? I have colour logos and I want these to show up in Greyed out Watermark style (only for the cover page background). I am unsure how to implement the code shown on page 6 of the linked pdf.

The rest of my thesis is showing up correctly with the code in the preamble (especially when I implement the twosided option in the document class). I want the Cover Page, Title Page to show up correctly (even when the twosided option is chosen and with an empty page after the Title Page) so that when it is sent out to print, it comes out as intended.

This is one of the last bits of my thesis I am trying to figure out. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Easiest solution: Use an image editor to change the logo. A bit more difficult (but TeXy): Have a look at the `decodearray` option of graphicx.

Comment: You could also play with the opacity: add `\usepackage{pgf}` in the preamble and then `\AddToShipoutPictureBG*{\pgfsetfillopacity{.15}\includegraphics[width=\paperwidth]{logo1}\pgfsetfillopacity{1}}`

Comment: Going with an image editor seems to be the easiest solution right now for me. 

Thank you for your help!

Comment: One can use `\if@twoside ... \else ... \fi` construction.  Also, one can create your own titlepage using things like `\pagestyle{empty}` and `\setcounter{page}{0}`.